# Is there a way to make .exe file from angular file?

Tags: angular, exe

I have an angular file and I want to execute it by something that I won't have to install angular CLI in every computer I will use this file. is there a way to make .exe file from this?

Comment: This can be done using Angular, Electron and Electron Packager- See [this blogpost](https://medium.com/@yannmjl/how-to-build-native-cross-platform-desktop-apps-with-angular-electron-bd1d6e3919b2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Electron with Angular CLI.

Please refer to the below medium blog I found after googling. It might help you and others.

[How to create Angular Desktop Apps](https://medium.com/@PhilippKief/angular-desktop-apps-a9ce9e3574e8)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a delayed reply, but this will help people who are working in angular and want to share their angular project with friends, where the .exe file will run without any environmental setup.

Yes, it is possible to make an angular project to .exe file using electron.

But my advice to avoid clinches is to install electron once you create a new project, not after completing the project, use step by step process carefully, even a single mistake will lead to discrepancies.

The common errors which I faced are,

1. The screen goes blank after the electron-build.
   Solution: - Go to angular.json file and change the output path to ""outputPath": "dist""
2. Create the electron specific main javascript file in the root directory.
3. Once the .exe file is clicked, it doesn't show any difference.
   Solution: Make sure you are trying to create an application where the "npm install electron --save-dev is given first once the project is created. (this might create problems in the future)